# How to list all available WP CLI commands?

Tags: php, wordpress

In my Wordpress multisite installation, `wp cli cmd-dump` is not listing all the available commands.

For example, install plugin [Any Ipsum](http://wp-cli.org/docs/tools/):

```
wp plugin install any-ipsum
wp plugin activate any-ipsum
```

After that, `wp help` says:

```
  wp

DESCRIPTION

  Manage WordPress through the command-line.

SYNOPSIS

  wp <command>

SUBCOMMANDS

  any-ipsum                   Interact with the Any Ipsum plugin
  ...
```

In addition, `wp any-ipsum generate-posts` seems to work.

So far so good.

However, `wp cli cmd-dump` does not list the command/subcommands (and this in turn seems to be the reason why `wp-cli` Node package does not find the command).

Any idea(s) how to make this work?

Comment: Try `wp help core`

Comment: What are you trying to do with `cmd-dump`? because there seems to be no commands registered as `cmd-dump`

Comment: @kisanme: http://wp-cli.org/commands/cli/cmd-dump/, used by https://www.npmjs.com/package/wp-cli

Answer (score 0):

`wp cli cmd-dump` lists the commands before the WordPress is loaded, thus it lists only the internal CLI commands.

In this particular case, the solution is to modify the `wp-cli` Node module, but that is another story.